# Extract a digit from an INT SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to do a function that substract an specific digit from an integer

EX:

I have the integer value 5648, and I want to extract only the 4.

The function should be something like

```
Extract(5648,2)
```

Where the first number is the integer, and the second number is which digit I want to extract, the function return only 1 digit from 0 to 9.

Thanks everybody

Comment: `floor(5648 / 10) % 10` returns 4.

Comment: *I want to do a function that substract an specific digit from an integer* Specific - from the beginning? from the end? something else?

Comment: If you want to do that the _VARCHAR_ way, a simple `mid(pINT,pDigit,1);` will do the job.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE GetDigitFromNumber(
    IN number INT,
    IN digit INT
)
BEGIN
    SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(CONVERT(number, CHAR(50)), digit + 1, 1) AS UNASSIGNED)
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks you!

I have changed it a little bit

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetDigitFromNumber;
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE GetDigitFromNumber(
    IN numero INT,
    IN digit INT
)
BEGIN
    SELECT SUBSTR(numero,digit,1);
END //
DELIMITER ;
CALL GetDigitFromNumber(321,1);

Comment: I don't think its a good idea to use SUBSTR on an INT even if mySQL is tolerating it at the moment. Maybe they will be more consequent in the future and you get an error. If you only use digit (instead of digit +1) you will get the first digit only by entering 1 in the procedure not 0 as you mentioned in your post

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to handle this.  One method is arithmetic:

```
select (5648 DIV power(10, 2-1)) % 10;
```

I don't see a reason to encapsulate this logic in a separate function.  But you can do so if you like.

Comment: That was my first approach but your logic is wrong. You will get the 3 digit if you enter 2 and the 2 digit when you enter 3. Its reverse order